# How to code in Perl CGI to include action with https, not http

Tags: perl, https, cgi

I have a server behind a load balancer. The LB translates out of https into http so the web server only sees http.

I have a perl script that uses CGI standard to generate an input form using

```
start_form( -action=>url())
```

Right now, the url in the HTML points to the http version of the url, not the https. What is the cleanest way to get it to always use https (if https is being used by the user)?

I've tried "-rewrite" as both 0 and 1 and that didn't make the difference.

Comment: Please see [my blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/11/modern-perl-cgi.html) and the responses for better options for creating CGI scripts than CGI.pm, if it is a case where you have such options. But to begin with, your load balancer should ideally be passing the header `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` for any of these solutions to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least according to the documentation and the code of `CGI.pm`, `url()` and `url( full => 1)` should both return `https://` if your CGI script was served from an `https://` URL. If the load balancer strips https and does not provide the appropriate headers, you can set `$ENV{HTTPS}` to `ON` to fake that in your script yourself:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(url);

$ENV{HTTPS} = 'ON';
print url();
```

#### See also

[CGI](https://metacpan.org/release/CGI)

Comment: I hope that it does not automatically use such headers, as this would be a possible vulnerability if the client can tell the code it's using a different protocol when there's no proxy setting the header! This is why you have to enable it with `MOJO_REVERSE_PROXY=1` or the hypnotoad `proxy` option in Mojolicious.